# Copy Items and versions using Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I’m trying to automate copying of latest versions of some files from a folder structure to another folder structure. I’m using the following endpoint for items and versions:

Items: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-POST/
Versions: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-versions-POST/

I keep getting the following error when using example 3 on the above pages for the copyFrom parameter even though I’m using url safe urn format as such:

urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.KKfHjZZ7S3unSVA62YHM7g%3Fversion%3D1

Version Error:

```
{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "id": "395d9751-780f-4d53-8162-e275026e48db",
      "status": "400",
      "code": "BAD_INPUT",
      "title": "One or more input values in the request were bad",
      "detail": "Request contains malformed Urn for copyFrom parameter."
    }
  ]
}

Item Error:

{
  "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "id": "8563555f-8dad-4ad0-9c6a-f0ff95ccbc60",
      "status": "400",
      "code": "BAD_INPUT",
      "title": "One or more input values in the request were bad",
      "detail": "Request contains urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.q4ytBrfgRCOJht2n9MKiOg%3Fversion%3D1, which is not a valid URN"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Were you able to fix the error?

Comment: Also send sample payload for further investigation.]